# Use QuantumGIS to bulk-import csv files

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, csv

I have a large set of .csv-files containing geographic information. Every dataset consists out of 2 .csv-files! This is my folder-structure. All files in Tracks are formatted equally and all in Routes too, obviously.

```
------- Tracks
-- 1.csv
-- 2.csv
-- 3.csv 
-- ...
------- Routes
-- 1.csv
-- 2.csv
-- 3.csv
-- ...
```

I can import them all for themselves, but that would take days of time (2000 datasets ...).

So what I would like to do is to load all those .csv-files at once and group them. So after the import I would like to have a lot of layer groups named 1,2,3 (like the files before the comma) and every group contains the layers representing the two files. Like this:

```
---- Group 1
-- tracks1
-- routes1
---- Group 2
-- tracks2
-- routes 2
---- Group 3
-- ...
```

Is that possible in any way? I cannot write python code, so I'm hoping for a plugin ;)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think a script (Python, Ruby, even a shell script) to wrap around OGR should do the trick.

Comment: As I said, I cannot write a script ... And I don't know what OGR is ...

Comment: Link to [OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)